# Glassdoor Alternative and usage of company data

Tags: data, salary

I have created Glassdoor alternative for specific country, which uses reviews and salaries submitted by users. I know that review is just users opinion on which company can't ask me to delete, but what about salary, do I have right to publicize companys salary? and if company asks me to delete all data about their salaries am I obligated to do so?

Comment: It depends on the country. Where are you doing this?

Comment: @RonTrunk In Georgia (Country one not state)